# Static IP not set after reboot

Tags: networking

I am currently trying to set my Raspberry Pi's IP address to static, and it works until I reboot and I have to run `sudo ifdown eth0; ifup eth0`.
I have set eth0 to static and have currently got the following configuration for it:

```
broadcast 192.168.0.250
address   192.168.0.250
submask   255.255.255.0
gateway   192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Is your static address and broadcast address really supposed to be the same? Also can you post your /etc/network/interfaces and the output of the ifconfig file - edit your question don't add it as a comment.

Comment: I'm relatively new to the Raspberry Pi and I had seen two different tutorials using two different things, so I set them both and it worked. Do I not need to have them both?

Comment: include a link to the tutorial you followed as well please. The pi is not normally the broadcast server for a network, that is usually the role of your router.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip)

Comment: If you are new to the Pi why not use dhcp and leave it to the router to do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you made an error on broadcast. It's supposed to be `192.168.0.255`.

[Source (RFC919)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc919)